# Django - How to save individual elements of a CharField when a form is submitted?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

When I submit my form, I want the text submitted as "note" to be split up, say by paragraph, and also saved to the "tag" part of my model automatically.

I have the following as my **models.py**

```
class NoteModel(models.Model):
    note = models.CharField(
        max_length = 5000
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.note}"

class NoteTagModel(models.Model):
    note = models.ForeignKey(
        NoteModel,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="notes",
        blank= False,
        null = True,
    )

    tag = models.CharField(
        max_length = 5000
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Note: {self.note} | Tag: {self.tag}"
```

I have the following as my **forms.py**

```
class NoteTagForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NoteTagModel
        fields = [
            'note',
            ]
```

Is there a way of doing this with Signals? Or would using a hidden inline formset be the best way? Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated.

I appreciate that JavaScript may be needed to separate out the text and declare as a variable to be saved as a form value.

Many thanks

Comment: You could override the save method on the modelform.. call super save() with commit=False, which will return an unsaved Note filled with the form data.   Take value from `note`..  do whatever string parsing you want.. take the first part and put it back into note.. save the object.. now create your NoteTags, populate and save them.

Comment: Thank you - do you have some example code / link to something similar I could see to help understand structure? Apologies - new to django!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with signals easily . Example code here .

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import NoteModel

@receiver(pre_save , sender = NoteModel) 
def take_data_from_note_and_add_to_tag(sender , instance , **kwargs):
    note = instance
    # splitting it in paragraph form . 
    data_list = note.split("\n")
    print(data_list)
    # check the paragraph you want in the tag field , i am choosing the first one.
    tag = data_list[0]
    note.tag = tag
```

Write this is in a new file named signals.py in the same app where you have your model .

then go to your apps.py and add a new function into it named ready and import your signals there .

Example code

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class SomeAppConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'app'

    # add your ready function here and import signals like this.
    def ready(self) : 
        import someapp.signals
```

This will work very nicely and will fulfill your required work.

Comment: Thank you - how can I save down all paragraphs as individual tags?

Comment: Create a different model for the tag say "Tag" then one the signal , for each paragraph create a foreignKey relation to the each tag which has been created .

Comment: Or other than that , you could do create a "Tag" model with relation of many to many field with note . This one would be probably easy and simple .

Comment: Thanks for all your help - I've managed to sort it

Comment: Great . Awesome work man.